# How do I pass the value of the variable pokemonname from an ejs file to a nodejs server side

Tags: html, node.js, api, express, ejs

**This is my other.ejs code:**

```
<input type="search" id="default-search" class="block p-4 pl-10 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg border border-gray-300 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="Search Pokemon" required="">
<button type="submit" id="searchpokemon" onclick="getPokemon()" class="text-white absolute right-2.5 bottom-2.5 bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-4 py-2 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">Search</button>

<script> function getPokemon() {
            const pokemonname = document.getElementById("default-search").value;
            //forchecking the value of pokemonname
            console.log(pokemonname)
        } </script>
```

**I want to pass the value of pokemonname to the ${passthevaluehere} in the node.js server side filenamed server.js which has this current code:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var weather = require('weather-js');
const dayjs = require('dayjs')
var fetchUrl = require("fetch").fetchUrl;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.listen(3000)
app.get('/other', async function (req, res) {
    fetchUrl(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${passthevaluehere}`, function(error, meta, body){
        var meals = JSON.parse(body)
        var data = {
            url: req.url,
            itemData: meals
        }
        console.log(data.itemData)
        res.render('other', {title:'OtherAPI', data});
    });
    
});
```

Still new to front-end and back-end developing.

Comment: I noticed you are calling the getPokemon function from the html, where in the function you are setting the pokemonName value, but you are printing name to the console not the pokemonName. Then in the last part of code section you are trying to add the name value to the URL. So, did you import the function there? or did you return the value of pokemonName from the function? Please check this to see if your problem solves or not!

Comment: removed some unnecessary parts in the function getPokemon() @Drystan will you still help me?

Answer (score 0):

Writing this answer without having any strong knowledge of Nodejs view engine. In Nodejs we have something called middleware functions.
In middleware we perform some actions/verifications then pass it to the next function. In NodeJS it would basically look like this:

```
route.get( getPokemon,searchPokemon);
```

So, where the `getPokemon` function will perform some actions, for example getting the value from the html and then we pass the data to the next function for further actions/verifications.

To pass the data we use `res.pokemon = pokemonname` /*Notice we're creating a new object named `pokemon` in the `res`*/

Now in the `searchPokemon` function we obtain the data using `res.pokemon` /*Here, res.pokemon is the same object which we created in the previous function.*/

An example will look like this:

```
router.get(verify,sendMess);

const verify=async(req,res,next)=>{
const pokemons=req.body;
if(pokemons) res.pokemonName=pokemons;
next(); /* To call the next function we have to use the next method available in the middlewares.*/
}

const sendMess=async(req,res)=>{
res.status(200).send(res.pokemonName);
}
```

If you still have some doubts using middleware, then [check out the docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html).

Answer (score 0):

Put the `<input>` field and the `<button>` in a `<form>`, remove the `getPokemon` function and the `onclick`, and instead make the button submit the entire form to the backend.

```html
<form action="other" method="get">
  <input type="search" id="default-search" name="searchterm" placeholder="Search Pokemon" required="">
  <button type="submit" id="searchpokemon">Search</button>
</form>
```

Now pressing the button will cause the browser to replace the current page with `GET http://your.server/other?searchterm=<what the user typed in the search field>`. In other words: It reloads the current page, but with a different search term.

The GET request will invoke your `server.js` file, where you must replace the (undefined) variable `${placethevaluehere}` with `${req.query.searchterm}`.

But it seems that your `other.ejs` code does not make use of the fields `title` and `data`, therefore the new page will look exactly like the previous one. Perhaps you did not share the full code of `other.ejs`.

Comment: yea this might work, but tell me how browser will know which url to point??

Comment: The browser invokes the URL from the `<form action="...">`.

Comment: ah okey. Got it!